# Javascript - Need to ask the user What is "x" times "y" where x and y are random numbers

Tags: javascript

So I am completely new to JavaScript and am having a hard time understanding what to do.

I need to ask the user to multiply 2 numbers between 1-10 that are randomly generated.

```
function Number(1, 10) {
    return Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1;
```

So how do I then write a function that uses the randomly generated numbers and puts the text in-between it and then checks the answer against the correct answer after it has been input?

I don't want someone to just do it but perhaps point me in the right direction.

Comment: When you define a function, the arguments must be variable names, not literal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to a function must be variables, not numbers. Also, Javascript already has a global function `Number` (it's the constructor for the `Number` object type), you shouldn't redefine it.

```
function randomNumber(low, high) {
    return Math.random() * (high - low) + 1;
}
```

You can get two numbers with:

```
var number1 = randomNumber(1, 10);
var number2 = randomNumber(1, 10);
```

Then you use concatenation to show them in the message to the user:

```
var answer = parseInt(prompt("What is " + number1 + " times " + number2 + "?"), 10);
```

Comment: Finally, `if (answer == number1 * number2) ...`

Comment: I thought he just needed to know how to display the messages. I assumed he knows how to compare numbers.

Comment: Well he talks about being completely new to JS, so I assumed not.  OTOH, he asked to be guided, not just shown how to do it.